# How to incorporate three different colours in random shapes in background of a webpage

Tags: html, css

Huddle landing page challenge :
[image]

I am new to front end development and learning via online course.
I am trying to do a challenge to design huddle landing page. can anyone please help me in below -
at the background of my webpage - there are three colors in random shapes. how can i achieve this using HTML and CSS>
attached is the webpage i need to achieve.
full body color is light grey.
and then two section each - one with white color and one has gradient of pink to violet. please help me to design the background color of this page.

I could not achieve this with Divs.

Comment: It is possible but it's pretty difficult, It would be easier if you can just use an image or create an SVG(plenty of tools available) and then use that instead.. but if you want to try something... here's some basic shapes...https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Answer (score 0):

That's an [SVG](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp) put as [background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) with [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/).